# to draw graph with mysql data

Tags: java, javascript

I need to draw a line graph with mysql data which has two columns. some one help me with a sample code.

Comment: How about http://code.google.com/apis/chart/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are number of options available to draw line chart in Java:

1. [Easy charts](http://www.objectplanet.com/easycharts/)
2. [jFree Charts](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/)
3. [jCharts](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JChartsLineChart.htm)
4. [Chart 2D](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/Chart2DLineChartWithScatterandDotontheLine.htm)
5. [Google Chart API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking at [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/)?

Answer (score 1):

Are the two columns the x and y axes of the graph? Why is it important that the data is present in mysql?

Anyways, for reading the data, you need to use jdbc: [jdbc tutorial](http://www.jdbc-tutorial.com/) (If you are using Java)

For building the actual graph, I would recommend [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html).